# how to parse X509 ssl certificate custom extension "certificate policy"?

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate, asn.1, x509certificate2

I am trying to parse X509 sertificate custom extension. (I have created a self signed certificate with custom extentions of type "certificate policy"). I need to parse this "certificate policy" and its values. Programatically I can get the name of the custom extention that is "certificate policy" but I can not get its values..The code that i am using is as the following:

```
    public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        var cert = (X509Certificate2)certificate;
        foreach (X509Extension ext in cert.Extensions)
        {
          //  AsnEncodedData x = new AsnEncodedData(ext.Oid, ext.RawData);
            MessageBox.Show("Name: " + ext.Oid.FriendlyName + "\nValue: " + ext.Oid.Value);

        }

        return true;
    }
```

This code onlye display "Certificate Policy" but I need the parse elements of the policy shown in below:

The values under the Certificate Policy elements:

```
[1]Certificate Policy:
     Policy Identifier=1.2.3.4
[2]Certificate Policy:
     Policy Identifier=1.5.6.7.8
[3]Certificate Policy:
     Policy Identifier=1.3.5.8
     [3,1]Policy Qualifier Info:
          Policy Qualifier Id=CPS
          Qualifier:
               Tarzano
     [3,2]Policy Qualifier Info:
          Policy Qualifier Id=User Notice
          Qualifier:
               Notice Reference:
                    Organization=Tarzano Ltd
                    Notice Number=1, 2, 3, 4
               Notice Text=Buraya mesaj yazilabilir
```

thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

At first, you will need an ASN.1 parser and use X.509 ASN.1 modules to decode extension value to a collection of policies. I wrote a managed class that extends existing X.509 extensions from .NEt library in my PowerShell PKI module. You can grab managed .dll or project sources from PSPKI project site: http://pspki.codeplex.com/ to get an idea how to decode this extension (I'm using my own ASN.1 parser, so code snippets here will not make much sense) if you want to have something your own (and do not rely on 3rd party assemblies).

there is a PKI.Core.dll (sources are attached too). X.509 extension classes are defined in System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates namespace. And documetation for this class in the library: http://pkix2.sysadmins.lv/library/html/T_System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509CertificatePoliciesExtension.htm
Extensions are made in a similar way (they inherit from X509Extension class) as .NET native with the exception that my extensions are fully native (do not use CryptoAPI c++ functions, like in .NET).

Comment: Thanks for the answer CryptoGuy. This class solved my problem:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.asnencodeddata(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no built-in support in .NET for parsing the ASN.1 data of x509 extensions, beyond the `.Format()` method, which reverts to returning a hex-encoded string if it encounters any unknown object type.

But the widely used BouncyCastle library, https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/, also available through NuGet, has good ASN.1 parsing support. Here is a sample that prints all the OID-type objects found in the extensions of a certificate. It works well on extensions that .NET cannot parse and display. The `Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Utilities.Asn1Dump.DumpAsString()` method is also useful.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;
public class AsnTest {
    public static void Main() {
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes("Test.x509"));
        foreach (var ext in certificate.Extensions) {
            // This is as far as we reliably get with native .NET libraries, switch to BouncyCastle for additional parsing
            var o = new Asn1InputStream(ext.RawData).ReadObject();
            var q = new Queue<Asn1Sequence>();
            var i = new List<DerObjectIdentifier>();
            if (o is Asn1Sequence) {
                q.Enqueue(o as Asn1Sequence);
            } else if (o is DerObjectIdentifier) {
                i.Add(o as DerObjectIdentifier);
            }
            while (q.Any()) {
                var s = q.Dequeue();
                i.AddRange(s.OfType<DerObjectIdentifier>());
                foreach (var n in s.OfType<Asn1Sequence>())
                {
                    q.Enqueue(n);
                }
            }
            if (i.Any()) {
                Console.WriteLine("Found the follwing OID value(s) in the " + ext.Oid.Value + " extension: " + string.Join(", ", i.Select(j => j.Id)));
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Found no OID values in the " + ext.Oid.Value + " extension.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```